# Реализация паттерна Репозиторий для работы со списком

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования, репозиторий

Реализация приложения-информационной системы.
Наличие таблицы с объектами, отображение простых полей и свойств объектов, выбор текущего типа отображаемых объектов.
Использование паттерна Репозиторий (Repository) для работы с данными.
Сортировка, фильтрация, добавление, удаление информации.
Сохранение в файл и чтение из файла в формате CSV, JSON или XML.

Вариант: Инженер, персона, Ведущий инженер, рабочая команда.

Помогите понять задание: иерархию классов и что имеется ввиду под репозиторием в контексте задачи. У меня же получается нет базы данных, а просто объекты из файлов считываются/записываются... сколько ни гуглю, везде примеры только с бд. Не доходит, как правильно репозиторий создать. Он же должен быть одним, или для инженеров и команд отдельные делать надо? И как примерно хотя бы это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

простите за глупые вопросы((

Comment: Вероятно, вопрос следовало бы разделить на два: один про организацию иерархии классов, второй - про репозиторий.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка не знаю что имеется ввиду, но подозреваю что тебе необходимо создать:

1. класс "Repository" в котором будет набор листов содержащих некие обьекты ("Engineer", "Commands" и др.)
2. дать возможность сериализовать и десериализовать в/из JSON или XML. CSV использовать не советую ибо там нет иерархической структуры в отличии от JSON и XML

```
class Repository {
   List<Engineer> Engineers = List<Engineer>()
   List<Command> Commands = List<Command>()

   public void Save(){}

   public void Load(){}
}

class Engineer {}

class Command {}
```

чет вроде такого, но с нормальным обьявлением полей у обьектов и с реализацией методов сериализации и десериализации

Comment: `Serializable` используется для бинарной и SOAP сериализации. Первая опасна, вторая чересчур громоздка и давно забыта. Обе давно устарели и не рекомендуются к использованию. / Автору нужны csv, json, xml. / Зачем атрибут `Serializable` навешан на сам класс репозитория?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, погуглил - и вправду. Пответ исправил, спасибо. По поводу csv - его стоит откинуть т.к. будут сложности в реализации сохранения в один файл. А сохранять каждую таблицу отдельным файлом как-то грустно

Comment: Спасибо! А методы сортировки, добавления и т.д. получается же в классе Repository писать? И еще один вопрос, по поводу классов. Какие поля у Command, просто List<Engineer>, или я что-то путаю?

Comment: Если хочешь отсортировать - просто сортируй любой из лист-ов в репозитории. Ничего не нужно писать отдельно. Как и добавления. Хотя вообще не знаю для чего сортировать данные в принципе в даной задаче. Команд - это просто второй тип обьектов. Вот есть у тебя обьект "работник/инженер". А второй тип обьекта хранящегося в репозитории пусть будет "место работы", а третье "команда", а четвертый тип "еда" и т.д. Это просто пример структуры для решения твоей задачи, а ты уже допиливай под конкретно твою задачу